# RUBY: TCPListener DOS string format

Tags: ruby, powershell

I have a Power Shell script which send data to a Ruby listener on a Linux machine. When I am sending the variable $env:COMPUTERNAME, or any other variable like 'report.csv', I have some weird output on Linux: '**report.csv??**' or '**report.csv^M**'.

As far as I know it is because DOS formats the ending with ^M. I have tried with .gsub but it is still not working as expected because I get '**report.csv?**' with single **?**. Is there any workaround?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'
require 'base64'

begin
  server = TCPServer.open(1234)
  client = server.accept
  hostname = client.gets()
  out_put = client.gets()

  File.open(hostname.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n"), "w") {|f| f.write(Base64.decode64(out_put))}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I apparently it worked with .chomp

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'
require 'base64'

begin
  server = TCPServer.open(1234)
  client = server.accept
  hostname = client.gets()
  out_put = client.gets()

  File.open(hostname.chomp, "w") {|f| f.write(Base64.decode64(out_put))}
end
```